# Calling PHPUnit from Artisan command will ignore the XML File

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-artisan

I have what I think is an uncommon issue but I'll try to explain as clear as I can. I have created a simple artisan command that does this

```
 /**
 * Execute the console command.
 */
public function handle()
{
    $this->info("==> Cleaning up reports and docs...");

    $command = new Process("rm -f tests/docs/* && rm -rf test/reports/*");
    $command->run();

    $this->warn("==> Reports and docs are clean");

    $this->info("==> Executing Tests Suite...");
    $command = new Process("vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html tests/reports --testdox-html tests/docs/reports.html -v --debug");
    $command->run();
    $this->info($command->getIncrementalOutput());

    $this->warn("==> report generated >> test/reports. Documentation generated >> test/docs/reports.html");
}
```

This could seems kinda odd but it is actually pretty useful, it launch the PHPUnit with the coverage support and other stuff. The problem is that if I run this command like `php artisan ludo237:full-test`  it will completely ignore the `phpunit.xml` in fact it will display and error saying that the MySQL database does not exists, even though I've set the sqlite connection inside my `phpunit.xml` speaking of which you can clearly see that is correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="true"/>
        <env name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost:8000"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:" />
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="log"/>
        <env name="MAIL_PRETEND" value="true"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

I know that I can simply create a bash alias for that command line, in fact this is my current hot fix, but at this point I'm just curious to understand why when I launch the phpunit command from the artisan command it ignores the XML file.

Does anyone have a clue about this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me really a lot to debug this, but in the end I found why it is not working.

First of all, let me clarify that is nothing wrong with your code, even there is nothing wrong with the `Process` class, you will get the same behavior even by using native `exec` function.

Second, the `phpunit.xml` file is totally being read, no issues at all.

Said that, the real issue resides, on PHPUnit that doesn't allow you to re-define ( or override ) any env variable, because [there is a check that prevents that](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.6/src/Util/Configuration.php#L542).

This is because Laravel is not parsing the `phpunit.xml` file itself, and in the moment you're calling it, it's already too late and [the environment variables are defined](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/blob/master/src/Loader.php#L345), either via `putenv`, `$_SERVER` and/or `$_ENV`.

Because of this, [I created an Issue on PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2353), which even in latest versions ( as of today ), this issue persist, even if this [was already asked in the past](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1276).

Unfortunately I have no solution yet for you, but let's cross our fingers and let's wait for PHPUnit to add the proposed `force` attribute :)

Best regards,
Julian

Comment: Thank you for.your effort let's see if the issue will have any update